# How to resolve "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object'" compilation error?

Tags: c#

I am getting the following errors when I compile my program:

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.Add(object)' has some
>   invalid arguments C:\Users\Jose\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\practice1\practice1\Form1.cs    26  13  practice1
>
> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to
>   'object'  C:\Users\Jose\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\practice1\practice1\Form1.cs    26  35  practice1

Here is the code I am struggling with:

```
namespace practice1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            talonary talonaryobj = new talonary(txtname.Text, txtlastname.Text,double.Parse(txtSalary.Text));

            lsttalonary.Items.Add(talonaryobj.name);
            lsttalonary.Items.Add(talonaryobj.lastname);
            lsttalonary.Items.Add(talonaryobj.calculateSalary);   //ERROR LINE
        }
    }    
}
```

This is the class I am using:

```
namespace practice1
{
    public class talonary
    {
       public string name;
       public string lastname;
       public double salary;

       public talonary(string n, string ln, double s)
       {
           this.name = n;
           this.lastname = ln;
           this.salary = s;
       }

       public string calculateSalary(double s)
       {
           s = s - (s * 0.05);
           return s.ToString();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: calculateSalary should have () after it where you're trying to add to the `Items` on `lsttalonary`. ALso it takes an argument... so you need to supply one

Comment: In C# the naming convention for classes and methods is TitleCase.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass arguments to the `calculateSalary` method. When you use a method name without arguments you are passing the method itself to the `Add` method, instead of calling the method and getting the result.

This

```
lsttalonary.Items.Add(talonaryobj.calculateSalary);   //ERROR LINE
```

Should be:

```
lsttalonary.Items.Add(talonaryobj.calculateSalary(talonaryobj.salary));   //Fixed line :)
```

It might be better to not have to pass the salary to the `calculateSalary` method at all though. Why not have it like this:

```
public string CalculateSalary()
{
    var s = this.salary - (this.salary * 0.05);
    return s.ToString();
}
```

And then you can call it like:

```
lsttalonary.Items.Add(talonaryobj.CalculateSalary());
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `lsttalonary.Items.Add(talonaryobj.calculateSalary(double s));` calls a method(calculateSalary) that gets passed in an argument that is a `double s`. You aren't giving it a `double` to perform its calculations with. It looks like it is supposed to return something related to salary, so perhaps you want `lsttalonary.Items.Add(talonaryobj.calculateSalary(talonaryobj.salary));`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, you're not passing a value to the `CalculateSalary` function.  I'll go a step further and say it should be a `Salary` property of type `double`.

```
        private double salary;
        public double Salary { get { return salary; } }
```

Then your code should handle formatting the salary value outside of the class.

I'd also recommend wrapping the fields in properties (probably read-only).

```
        private string name;
        private string lastname;

        public string Name { get { return name; } }
        public string Lastname { get { return lastname; } }
```

Then you'll need to modify your calling code.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            talonary talonaryobj = new talonary(txtname.Text, txtlastname.Text,double.Parse(txtSalary.Text));

            lsttalonary.Items.Add(talonaryobj.Name);
            lsttalonary.Items.Add(talonaryobj.Lastname);
            //lsttalonary.Items.Add(talonaryobj.calculateSalary);   //ERROR LINE
            lsttalonary.Items.Add(string.Format("##some format string here##", talonaryobj.Salary));
        }
```